# jQuery Phone validation not working as expected

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I've been trying to validate the phone number in jQuery, but for some reason the code fails to validate the condition as expected.

**HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="custReg.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custRegistration.css">
</head>
<body bgcolor ="lightgray" fontcolor="red">
    <form action="" name="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="">

        <div id="container">
            <fieldset>
                <legend style="background-color: aqua;">Registration Page</legend>
    <div id="primaryContact">Primary Contact No.</div>
                <div id="alternateContact">Alternate Contact No.</div>  

                <div id="contactNoBlock">
                    <input type="text" name="primaryNumber" value="+91-" id="primaryNumber"  class="textBox1" />   <!--  -->
                    <input type="text" name="altNumber" value="+91-" id="altNumber" class="textBox1" />
                </div>

                <div id="contact_error_msg"></div>
                <br>
</div> <!-- <div id="container"> closes here  -->

        </fieldset>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS code:**

```
fieldset {
    width: 120%;
    border: solid 1px black;}

legend {
    color: black;
    font-style: italic;
    font-size: 15px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: 25px; } 


.textBox1 {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 280px;}

#primaryContact{
    margin-left:10px;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a77;
    position: relative;
    top:12px;

}

#alternateContact{

    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a77;
    position: relative;
    left: 335px;
    top:-5px;

}
```

**jQuery code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var altContactNo = $('#altNumber');
    var contactErrorMsg = $('#contact_error_msg');
    var regexIn = /\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/ ;

    $(altContactNo).blur(function(){

     var value = $(altContactNo).val();  
     alert(value);


     if(value.length<=4){     
      $(contactErrorMsg).text("Please enter Alternate Contact Number");
      $(this).css('border','1px solid red');
   }

     else if(!regexIn.test(value)){
         $(contactErrorMsg).text("Only digits accepted "); 
         $(this).css('border','1px solid red');  
     }

     else if ((value.length>=4) && (value.length<=14)){
         $(contactErrorMsg).text("Number should be exact 10 digits"); 
         $(this).css('border','1px solid red'); 
    } 



     else{
          $(this).css('border','1px solid green');
          $(contactErrorMsg).text(""); 
         }

});


});
```

**Challenges that I'm facing with this code:**

> - When I enter any non-numeric digit, the code diplays the error as
>     expected - **`"Only digits accepted"`** However, once I delete the
>     non-numeric digit & replace it with a numeric digit, the same error
>     message still persists, which is incorrect.
> - To let off go the above error, I need to wait till the numeric count reaches 10 digits **(since I'm targetting 10 digit cell number)**. During this entire process, the above error message continues to show up. Let's say, if I enter number as **785** and come out of the input-box, it should throw **"Number should be exact 10 digits"** `error-message` until it reaches 10 digits count. However, this is not happening at this point of time.
> - Further, even after the count goes beyond the stipulated 10 digits mark, no error-message is displayed. What I'm wanting is, **`after 10-digits mark is crossed`**, an **`error-message should flash stating`** **`"Number should be exact 10 digits"`** and box should turn red.

**How do I get the above things resolved ?** Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: ask a single question.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - **Try to run the code, you would understand what I'm talking about.**  Question might look lengthy, but its a single question only.

Comment: Use `keypress` instead of `blur`, use html5 `maxlength` attribute to prevent >10 digits.

Comment: I'm not ready to run your code since i'm not from js background. Your problem would be solved simply if you reduce the question length. Instead of posting the whole code, you may ask like, "hey i want the password field to allow this and this chars but not this. I tried this, but it fails," like that.

Comment: Incidentally, `altContactNo` is already a jQuery object. There is no need for `$(altContactNo)`. Same goes for `contactErrorMsg`.

Comment: @ShaunakD - I can't use maxlength attribute, because if I do so, I would need to change the **input type="number"**. While doing that, I lose out on the number-code that's flashing on the input-text box which is **+91-** and I wish to show it at any cost.  Unfortunately, that's the reason even after knowing it, had to revert to the original code.

Comment: @RizkyFakkel - Need your urgent attention... Please help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're validating against the regex and you're showing the "Only digits accepted " when it doesn't match the regex **for any reason**.  That means you will see this message any time what is entered doesn't match, whether it is due to character choice or length or spacing.

For the same reason, you're not seeing the "Number should be exact 10 digits" message because when there are less than 10 digits, it doesn't match the regex and falls into that second if clause.

Depending on how different languages handle regex validation, some implementations will allow for multiple matches.  If that is the case then "1234567890123" could match because "1234567890" matched.  Try putting "^" at the start and "$" at the end of the your regex which will limit the validation to make it match one single time only.

Comment: @lonsberry - Unfortunately the code produces no results, when I put the **"^" at the start and "$" at the end of the regex**. Did try that trick before posting the question, but it produced no fruitful results.

Comment: @Lonsberry - The jQuery file doesn't run at all.

Comment: Make sure you're putting them inside the "/" which in this case are acting as the delimiters.

Comment: Also, double check the logic in your 3rd if test, I think you're doing the opposite of what you're intending.

Comment: @Lonsberry - The result the same. **Getting error message as "invalid regexp group"**

Comment: Make sure it looks like this 

`var regexIn = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})$/;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80825/discussion-between-jason-lonsberry-and-mindfreak).

Comment: @Lonsberry - Thanks Lonsberry, I did manage to get the solution myself.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your question directly, but you can also verify input field based on an attribute introduced to inputs in HTML5, pattern. Like so:

```
<input type="tel" pattern="\+91\-[0-9]{3}[ .-][0-9]{3}[ .-][0-9]{4}" value="+91-" />
```

Result:

http://jsfiddle.net/wojtekmaj/g28cqnLw/

Also, in my opinion such a strict verification of a number should only be used in cases when something might go horribly wrong if the user does not type precise format you want. This is horrible for user experience.

Comment: @Maj - I have found the solution myself... Any ways thanks for your efforts !!